# Read performance of SQL Server data files data from Azure BLOB

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I have a setup where there is SQL Server on premises (MS SQL Server 2016 13.0.5366.0) but database files (log and data) are stored in cloud storage account. Setup described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/sql-server-data-files-in-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-2016).

The interesting part is the performance of physical reads of data. Basically i am executing very simple select statement from table and cleaning buffers/cache before running it.

- If i read data in single thread query from table and physical reads
  are needed i get maximum network utilization never exceeding **32
  Mbps**- much slower than i expect
- If i read data in many threads that also requires physical reads i
  get maximum network utilization close to **500 Mbps** that is something
  that i would expect.

**Trying to understand:**

- Why sequential execution are not reading data faster? Is there some limits of max read performance for single thread?
- Why query is not starting to work parallel so that multiple threads would read same data file (and in that way achieving higher performance)?

Did try splitting data to multiple data files- no affect.

Did try query hints (query was still not executed in parallel)

```
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8649) 

OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'))
```

Comment: This is more or less working as designed. A trivial `SELECT * FROM [table]` will yield a trivial plan; a parallel plan will not even be considered in this case, even if the table is enormous. In my tests, a query of the form `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [non-nullable-column] = [non-nullable-column]` *will* be parallelized, if the hint is supplied. Note that this may not necessarily use server resources optimally, as the data still needs to be gathered for sequential transmission -- parallel reads of non-overlapping ranges don't have this problem.

Comment: As to why sequential read performance isn't better, this has multiple causes, most of them beyond your control -- TDS is a dinosaur protocol and the engine does especially poorly if your table has very broad rows. You can decrease the overhead by using a larger packet size (`Packet Size=32767` in your connection string) but you will find that even with that, using explicit parallelism on the client end can improve performance beyond what individual queries can give you, even when those use parallelism on the server end. This is not even specific to Azure.

Comment: @JeroenMostert in this case i am connecting to SQL Server instance that is on local server. Data however is in cloud and SQL Server is managing that connection separately. So connection string to server would not affect the speed of data retrieval from cloud.

Comment: No, but it does affect the speed of data retrieval from your SQL Server instance to your client, which is typically just as significant a bottleneck. Or, to put it differently, the bottleneck is not the data transfer from the cloud to the local machine -- if it was, explicit parallel reading would not improve it. The cloud can essentially be considered as if it was a slow harddisk, and should yield much the same performance characteristics.